# MySQL - Count all rows in name specific tables, which are older than 1 day

Tags: mysql

This is the statement I am using to get the count of all rows from tables where name of the table includes word 'devices'.

```
SELECT SUM(TABLE_ROWS) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
  WHERE TABLE_NAME like '%devices%'
```

And above works wonderfully. However I need to get the count of only those rows which had changes during the last 24 hours.

This should be easy to do, because each '%devices%' table has a column named dateofinstall where I store the unix timestamp (epoch).

So naturally I wanted to use the following statement:

```
SELECT SUM(TABLE_ROWS) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
   WHERE TABLE_NAME like '%devices%' 
     and dateofinstall >= unix_timestamp(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

However this doesn't seem to work!

Any other way of getting the count of all rows in name specific tables, which are older than 1 day?

--

FOUND A CORRECT ANSWER (thanks to user: **Alma Do**):

This builds a new query, which upon execution returns count within 24 hours.

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT('SELECT SUM(rowscount) FROM (', 
         GROUP_CONCAT(sqlcount SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL '), 
         ') as initunion') 
FROM 
  (SELECT 
    CONCAT('SELECT COUNT(1) AS rowscount FROM `',
    TABLE_SCHEMA,
    '`.`',
    TABLE_NAME,
    '` WHERE dateofinstall>= unix_timestamp(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 1 DAY)') as sqlcount 
   FROM 
     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
   WHERE 
     TABLE_NAME like '%devices%') as initcount;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not do that directly. That is because - even if `TABLE_ROWS` holds data that relied to actual table data, it can not be used with conditions in any case and `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` itself does not contains any table *data*, only *metadata*.

However, there's a way to do this with building SQL query by another SQL query. It will be like:

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT('SELECT SUM(rowscount) FROM (', 
         GROUP_CONCAT(sqlcount SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL '), 
         ') as initunion') 
FROM 
  (SELECT 
    CONCAT('SELECT COUNT(1) AS rowscount FROM `',
    TABLE_SCHEMA,
    '`.`',
    TABLE_NAME,
    '` WHERE dateofinstall<NOW()-INTERVAL 24 HOUR') as sqlcount 
   FROM 
     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
   WHERE 
     TABLE_NAME like '%devices%') as initcount;
```

-the resulting string will be valid SQL and you will be able to execute that via [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html). For example:

```
SET group_concat_max_len = 32000;
SET @sql = (SELECT 
  CONCAT('SELECT SUM(rowscount) FROM (', 
         GROUP_CONCAT(sqlcount SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL '), 
         ') as initunion') 
FROM 
  (SELECT 
    CONCAT('SELECT COUNT(1) AS rowscount FROM `',
    TABLE_SCHEMA,
    '`.`',
    TABLE_NAME,
    '` WHERE dateofinstall<NOW()-INTERVAL 24 HOUR') as sqlcount 
   FROM 
     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
   WHERE 
     TABLE_NAME like '%devices%') as initcount);
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

-note, that [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) has restriction for length of returned string, so you may want to adjust [`group_concat_max_len`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) for your session.

Also, please, note, that in common case building one query by another query is an architecture smell (because of unpredictable SQL length, at least), but in your case this is acceptable since you will not have too many tables, obviously.

Comment: First of all thank you for trying to help. I've executed the first example and it did built a new query as you've mentioned. I've executed this new sql query, but the result of the new query is still showing total number of all rows, not those within last 24 hours. Second sql you've prepared is giving me an error in sql syntax.

Comment: Ok, I've figured it out, I just needed to add the proper 24 hour interval statement to your first example. Fantastic.

Comment: @jjj my SQL was a sample. Yes, you should adjust it to your issue

Comment: @jjj also found why second was an error: mistype `@s` instead of `@sql` in `PREPARE`, fixed